# perform a simple check on the form fields (NotEmpty)

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

This is my method `SaveClient()` that create a new client even if all fields are empty !

```
public void SaveClient() {

    client = new Client();
    client.setNom(nom);
    client.setPrenom(prenom);
    client.setAdresse(adresse);
    client.setDomaine(domaine);
    client.setRaisonSociale(raisonSociale);
    client.setDateDAbonnement(dateDAbonnement);
    client.setDateFAbonnement(dateFAbonnement);
    client.setType(type);
    client.setEmail(email);
    client.setnFixe(nFixe);
    client.setnGsm(nGsm);
    client.setnFixe2(nFixe2);
    client.setnGsm2(nGsm2);
    client.setVille(ville);
    client.setPays(pays);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Client>> violations = validator
            .validate(client);
    basicController.<Client> processValidation(violations);

    if (violations.size() == 0) {
        clientBean.creerClient(client);
        basicController.addMessage(" Client has been created successfully",
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, null);}
```

Comment: I want to add a verification check to not add Client if All fields are Empty !

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the inputs to the model directly instead of flattening out and/or duplicating the model into the backing bean.

I.e. do **not** do

```
@Named
public class Bean {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    // ...

    public void save() {
        Client client = new Client(firstname, lastname, address /* , ...*/);
        clientService.save(client);
    }

}
```

with

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.firstname}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.lastname}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.address}" />
...
```

But instead do

```
@Named
public class Bean {

    private Client client;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        client = new Client();
    }

    public void save() {
        clientService.save(client);
    }

}
```

with

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.client.firstname}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.client.lastname}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.client.address}" />
...
```

Provided that you've a

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @NotNull
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull
    private String address;

    // ...
}
```

This way JSF will automatically take any bean validation annotations in `Client` class into account. Also, this way you end up with much simpler code without unnecessary duplication.